# How do I get full resolution out of my monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, dvi, displayport

I have a [Monoprice 27in IPS-ZERO-G Slim Monitor WQHD 2560x1440](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=10509) - Dual Link DVI, VGA with a max resolution of 2560 x 1440 connected to a [NVIDIA Quadro K620](https://www.pny.com/nvidia_quadro_k620) video card. The Connection is as follows:

> Monitor (DVI-D) >> DVI-D Cable >> Display Port Adapter >> Display Port Input on video card.

With this setup my monitor is limited to a max resolution of 1920 x 1080. Anything above that does not display (screen goes black). I think it has to do with not having a display port on the monitor itself.

Will buying a [USB powered DVI-D to displayport](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XYBA72) link adapter allow my monitor to use maximum resolution?

Comment: @JakeGould, please take a look at the link to the adapter I am talking about. The adapter is DVI-D to DisplayPort. It is only powered by the USB.

Comment: DVI-D does not mean "dual link DVI". The adapter you mentioned is the right one, but it is not "DVI-D to DisplayPort", it is "DisplayPort to Dual Link DVI ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Monoprice included a defective cable with the monitor. They sent me a new one and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a “DisplayPort -> Dual Link DVI adapter”, like this: [“Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter”](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter)